# Word VBA: how to split paragraph into two styles?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I made a program that goes through the document and if there is a paragraph with tab in it, it splits it in two:

```
sSPlit = Split(aPara.Range.Text, vbTab)
aPara.Range.Text = sSPlit(0) & vbCrLf & sSPlit(1)
```

That works great. The problem is, I'd like the first splitted paragraph to have "Style1" and the second "Style2".

```
aPara.Style = "Style1"
```

adds this style to the next, yet unsplitted paragraph. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to calculate the ranges to apply the style to and then simply retrieve the range of calculated characters, e.g.:

```
Dim par1Start As Integer
Dim par2Start As Integer

par1Start = aPara.Range.Start
par2Start = par1Start + Len(sSplit(0)) + 1

aPara.Range.Text = sSplit(0) & vbCrLf & sSplit(1)

ActiveDocument.Range(par1Start, par2Start).Style = "Style1"
ActiveDocument.Range(par2Start, par2Start + Len(sSplit(1))).Style = "Style2"
```